# How Do I Purchase Ubuntu One Songs Without Using Ubuntu One File Sharing?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, dropbox

I want to use DropBox instead of Ubuntu One. But I like the idea of buying MP3s for 88 cents from Ubuntu One because it can help contribute cash to the Ubuntu project.

I have disabled and uninstalled Ubuntu One client on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS workstation. Is there a way that I can still purchase and download MP3s from Ubuntu One without installing the Ubuntu One client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you buy the music via searching for it using the Amazon search in the firefox search bar, your purchase will support Canonical, and you won't need Ubuntu One.

[image: screenshot of Amazon search in the firefox search bar]

Only works in some countries (US, UK, Germany, France, Austria and Switzerland - although I'm not certain the affiliate code works from all of them), and not sure what the download experience is like (nor whether they give you permission to copy the resulting files, nor whether they allow and/or enable you to stream to your mobile device - both of which I don't think I could live without these days).

Comment: Clever! :) I really like this.

Comment: I would not do this.  Downloading purchased music from Amazon via their crappy Linux download tools is a HUGE pain...especially on 64bit.  Just pay the $39/year for UbuntuOne and disable sync.

Answer (score 7):

You must have an Ubuntu One account (and be subscribed to Ubuntu One Basic) to buy music from the Ubuntu One Music Store. You must also have added your computer to Ubuntu One to buy music.

If you do not want to sync your files using Ubuntu One, you can disable file sync in Ubuntu One Preferences. Disabling file sync will prevent purchased songs from downloading to your desktop. You will then need to download your purchased songs from the Ubuntu One website at https://one.ubuntu.com/files

Purchased songs will be available for streaming from your personal cloud to your iPhone or Android phone if you wanted to sign up for Ubuntu One Mobile.